# Visual Studio 2010 generates an "error" on build

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ocx

I've got a project that uses a third party OCX.  The OCX was recently updated with a new method.  I'm trying to insert code that utilizes that new method:

```
EPS.Refresh_IO_Link(ControllerRow("ControllerPort"), ControllerRow("ControllerSettings"))
```

It compiles fine, but when I try to run it from within VS2010 it generates the following error:

```
'Refresh_IO_Link' is not a member of 'AxEPSIO.AxctlEPSIO'.
```

This is not true.  It shows up in Intellisense, and if I do a rebuild the error goes away.  However running it in debug mode always generates the error.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution, but have the same error each time.

Comment: What is the third party component? Have you tried consulting the vendor?

Comment: Heh, I don't know why I said third-party... it was developed in-house in VB6.  The OCX works in another project, just not this one.  The other project had the same problem, but a clean/rebuild fixed it.  I honestly don't think it's the component's fault, but instead it's VS2k10 being confused after replacing the old version of the OCX with a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLL Hell. Remove the reference to the .ocx in the project, and then re-add it. If the .ocx was not compiled with binary compatibility, then you are likely still referencing the old version of the .ocx. Also, make sure the new .ocx is registered on your PC (regsrv32.exe).